# Select only the remaining records from a n:m table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all records that are not already in a n:m type of query...

i have a table called 'artwork' like this:

```
artwork_id  caption                              filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
1           Moonlight Front cover                3483490.jpg
2           Take it Inlay                        2984560.jpg
3           Moonlight Front Cover (UK Release)   gh893ed.jpg
4           CD ....                              86re956.jpg
5           CD 3 ...                             84wefg8.jpg
```

I have a n:m table called 'album_artwork' like this:

```
album_id  artwork_id  position
-------------------------------
1         1           1
23        1           1
8         2           5
1         2           2
```

I have a form that lets the user select artwork for an album, but i don't want the user to repeat entries... So i would like to show the user the remaining artwork... So for example, for the album with an id of 1, the select input will display the following options

```
3 Moonlight Front Cover (UK Release)
4 CD ...
5 CD 3 ...
```

artwork_id 1 and and artwork_id 2 will not be part of the select options because the artwork_id entry for the album_id 1 already exist in the n:m album_artwork database

How do i select only the remaining ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `NOT EXISTS` to filter the `artwork_id` which are already present in `album_artwork`:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM 
  artwork a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    /* NOT EXISTS subquery returns artwork_id's from album_artwork already present */
    SELECT artwork_id FROM album_artwork aw 
    WHERE
      album_id = $your_album_id
      AND a.artwork_id = aw.artwork_id
  )
```

#### [Here is a demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c809/1) on SQLFiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` to only select `artwork` rows that are not in an array of already used `artwork` for the known `album`.

```
SELECT
 artwork_id,caption,filename
FROM 
 artwork
WHERE
 artwork_id
NOT IN
   (SELECT artwork_id FROM album_artwork WHERE album_id = $album_id)
```

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4289c/2)